# treating web page like directory

Tags: mount, directory, download, web

I'm a Mac user and I want to `cd` to a web page and then `cp` some files onto a local directory. Is there a way to do this?

This is the page I'm referring to: http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Herbster/GI07/week5/

Comment: You can't cd to a webiste, you'll have to use `wget` or `curl -O` to download the files. If you want to simulate cd I guess you could do something like this, `variable="http://yourwebsite.com/yourdirectory" && curl -O $variable/yourfile && curl -O $variable/yourotherfile` etc.

Comment: Why not just ask M.Herbster for the files you want. Academics are often willing to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like *DisplayName* mentioned in his respond you can't **cd** into a website. **cd** command works only in directories on your local machine if not used with another command to remotely access a machine like **ssh**.
You need a command like **wget** or **curl** to download something from web. In addition to the **curl** examples you could use **wget** like this:

**download a certain file**
`wget http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Herbster/GI07/week5/dtrain123.dat`
**download files with a certain file extension from this directory**
`wget -rl1 -A .dat http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Herbster/GI07/week5/`
**download all files from this directory**
`wget -r -np -l1 http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Herbster/GI07/week5/`

> **explanation of command options:**
>   -r recursive download (careful with that!)
>   -A comma seperated list of allowed file extensions
>   -l maxdepth of recursion while 'inf' or '0' means infinite.
>   -np omits parent directories
>   *url's used refer to the url you mentioned*

Answer (score 2):

In general, it isn't possible to navigate a website like a directory, because there's no standard way to list the files inside a directory. In fact, there isn't even a concept of directory on the web: whether `http://foo/bar/wibble` serves a file called `wibble` in a directory called `bar` is a matter of how the server is designed, it doesn't have to be that way. It's also possible to have different content depending on the number of slashes (e.g. `http://foo/bar/wibble` and `http://foo/bar/wibble/` and `http://foo/bar//wibble` return different content), which cannot be represented as tree of file paths.

Note that unlike what others have claimed here, it *is* possible to navigate remote files as if they were local. For example, you can `cd` into an FTP site if you mount it; ways to do that include [Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) on OS X, [gvfs-mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html) on Linux with Gnome, [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) on Linux or OS X, and [AVFS](http://sourceforge.net/p/avf/mailman/message/25658571/). All of these work through [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which is a framework to expose basically anything as a directory tree.

There's no general way to expose a web server as a directory tree, though, because it doesn't really have this tree structure. Also, requests to the same URL can return different content (based on the client's language preferences, user agent, cookies, etc.).

The server you want happens to serve a page that looks like a directory listing when you access certain URLs. But that page is formatted on the server, it isn't something that your browser formats like when accessing an FTP site. In principle, it would be possible for the client to parse this and generate a directory listing; for example there's an [httpfs](https://github.com/cyrus-and/httpfs) that does this but it only supports the output for a specific way to format the directory listing on the server site. There's actually a standard protocol for accessing directory trees over HTTP — [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) — but it isn't used very often. I'm not aware of an implementation that parses Apache's standard directory listing, which I think is what your site serves.

If you want to download a file on the command line, you can use [`curl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/curl.1.html). If you want to download all the files in a directory, you can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (not included on OSX but can be installed via package managers):

```
wget -r -np -l1 http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Herbster/GI07/week5/
```

`wget -r -np http://…` is analogous to `cp -r http://… .`, but the recursion works differently. `cp` copies directories by enumerating the files in them, including subdirectories on which it acts recursively, and copies regular files by creating a file with the same content. On the web, there's no distinction between directories and regular files; `wget` recurses by following all the links in an HTML page. The option `-r` tells `wget` to copy recursively, and `-np` tells it not to follow links that point “up” — which is a textual matter: it only follows links whose target begins with `http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Herbster/GI07/week5/` (with rules for relative links that achieve the same result). The option `-l1` is an extra safety to tell it to stop recursing after one level (i.e. it follows links from the HTML file at the given URL, and then stops); it isn't necessary, but it's recommended to avoid situations where the recursive download gives you a lot more material than you'd originally intended because of extra links that you hadn't noticed.

Comment: It was hard to choose which answer to accept. While the answer I accepted went more into the specifics of `wget`, your answer has more exposition and is more interesting. Thanks for this answer.